# Can not change number of cores for spark executors after first run

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark 2.1.0 and I noticed strange behavior in my spark streaming application. I can not change number of cores for executor once they were set up during first run. Application is run on spark standalone cluster.

First time I run my spark streaming app in this way

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options -Denv=test --master spark://my_server:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 3G  --driver-cores 4  --executor-memory 3G --executor-cores 4 --conf spark.metrics.conf=/usr/lib/spark/conf/metrics_analytics.properties --class com.MyApp hdfs:///apps/app.jar
```

Than I stopped my app

```
spark-submit --master spark://my_server:6066 --kill driver-20170807163818-0051
```

and I run my spark (3 core per executor)

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options -Denv=test --master spark://my_server:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 3G  --driver-cores 4  --executor-memory 3G --executor-cores 3 --conf spark.metrics.conf=/usr/lib/spark/conf/metrics_analytics.properties --class com.MyApp hdfs:///apps/app.jar

{[my_server] out:   "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
[my_server] out:   "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20170808093847-0052",
[my_servero] out:   "serverSparkVersion" : "2.1.0",
[my_server] out:   "submissionId" : "driver-20170808093847-0052",
[my_server] out:   "success" : true
[my_server] out: }
```

here is my spark config

```
  .setMaster(configuration.spark.master) //it is better to set master as a spark submit param
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", configuration.cassandra.server)
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", configuration.cassandra.user)
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", configuration.cassandra.password)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", configuration.cassandra.timeout.toString)
  .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", configuration.spark.maxRatePerPartition.toString)
  .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
  .set("spark.metrics.namespace", "my-app")
  .set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "LOCAL_QUORUM")
```

Even when I change number of cores for executor, my application still uses 4 cores  instead of 3.
I also removed checkpoint data but it hasn't helped.

I'm wondering if it is only UI problem or I can not change configuration for my application because of some reason (some metadata stored for job by app name ?).

Here is my
[Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxVBQ.png)

Comment: Can you please include a screen shot of the Spark UI Environment tab to verify that you have correctly setup the job to run on 3 executor cores instead of 4 cores?

Comment: Yep here is my Spark UI [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxVBQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've resolved the problem there were two issues which caused the problem.

1. --num-executors seems to not work for Standalone cluster. I had to use --total-executor-cores instead.
2. I had to clean up checkpoint directory after I had changed the number of cores in order to make Spark seeing changes.

This checkpointing is a really pain regarding deploying app, changing configuration, broadcasts etc. Ok structured streaming solves some issues but still not everyone is going to use this new API.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How is checkpoint directory cleaned up? Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: You need to clean up checkpoint directory on your own every time you deploy new version of your streaming app.
`hadoop fs -rm -r -f /checkpoint`

Checkpoint directory is configured by
`val ssc = new StreamingContext`
`//checkpoint: "hdfs://<hdfs-name-HA>/checkpoint/"`
`ssc.checkpoint(configuration.spark.checkpoint) // set checkpoint directory`
I used to use fabfile scripts to do the deployment. The better way would be using Spark Job Server but I am not sure how it is the cleaning implemented in that solution.